# Как результат одной функции передать в другую как массив аргументов?

Tags: shell, zsh

Zsh-скрипт. Есть функция, которая выдает несколько строк. Хотелось бы их передать в другую функцию, чтобы одна строка считалась одним аргументом.

```
foo() {
    echo "a b c";
    echo "d e f";
}

$foo
a b c 
d e f

bar() {
    echo "\$1=";
    echo $1;
    echo "\$2=";
    echo $2;
}
```

Что я хочу

```
$ bar magic(foo)
$1=
a b c
$2=
d e f
```

Пробовал варианты:

```
$ bar $(foo)
$1=
a
$2=
b


$ bar "$(foo)"
$1=
a b c
d e f
$2=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Вариант 1

Сработает такой синтаксис:

```
bar "${(f):-$(foo)}"
```

Подробнее о каждом элементе синтаксиса:

1. `$(foo)` раскрывается как одна строка, которая может содержать внутри себя символ(ы) перевода строки (LF, line feed, `\n`).
2. `${:-значение}` разворачивается в строку, следующую после `:-`. В данном случае само по себе это не меняет результат, но позволяет нам использовать флаги развертки параметров к любому тексту (в том числе к тому, который мы получаем в пункте 1).
3. `${(f)...}` делит строку на отдельные аргументы по разрывам строки. То есть в данном случае на два аргумента по единственному разрыву между ними.

#### Вариант 2

Заставляем `bar` читать вывод `foo` построчно.

```
bar() {
    read -r argument1;
    read -r argument2;

    echo "\$1=";
    echo $argument1;
    echo "\$2=";
    echo $argument2;
}
```

<sub>на основе ответов к [собственному вопросу на EN.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31743111/2790048)</sub>